# Retrieving "amount" from primary account using Coinbase API

Tags: python, coinbase-api

I'm very new to APIs so this question might be super obvious to most. Using python I am trying to retrieve my Bitcoin balance in BTC, so that I can make a bot that detects how much I have in my Bitcoin wallet and sell a percentage of that value. However, I am having difficulties actually retrieving the amount of BTC in my primary account. I am able to find my alt coin balances using these lines:

`accounts = client.get_accounts()  for wallet in accounts.data: print(str(wallet['name'])+str(wallet['native_balance']))`

However, I am not quite sure how to retrieve the amount value from my primary account, and BTC doesn't show up in this set when I run it.
on coinbases api dev site, this is how it says the data is setup:

```
  {
  "pagination": {
    "ending_before": null,
    "starting_after": null,
    "limit": 25,
    "order": "desc",
    "previous_uri": null,
    "next_uri": null
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "58542935-67b5-56e1-a3f9-42686e07fa40",
      "name": "My Vault",
      "primary": false,
      "type": "vault",
      "currency": "BTC",
      "balance": {
        "amount": "4.00000000",
        "currency": "BTC"
      },
      "created_at": "2015-01-31T20:49:02Z",
      "updated_at": "2015-01-31T20:49:02Z",
      "resource": "account",
      "resource_path": "/v2/accounts/58542935-67b5-56e1-a3f9-42686e07fa40",
      "ready": true
    },
    {
      "id": "2bbf394c-193b-5b2a-9155-3b4732659ede",
      "name": "My Wallet",
      "primary": true,
      "type": "wallet",
      "currency": "BTC",
      "balance": {
        "amount": "39.59000000",
        "currency": "BTC"
      },
      "created_at": "2015-01-31T20:49:02Z",
      "updated_at": "2015-01-31T20:49:02Z",
      "resource": "account",
      "resource_path": "/v2/accounts/2bbf394c-193b-5b2a-9155-3b4732659ede"
    }
  ]
}
```

first thought was to figure out how to reverse engineer what makes the lines work for the wallets work, but everything I've tried hasn't worked, so clearly I am just unaware of how `get_primary_account()` works

All I want is "amount" which is within "data", and to be able to convert that to an float. Any help?

Comment: help me out, i don't see get_primary_account in the python coinbase api.

Comment: Get_primary_account is the command to retrieve the dataset that i listed below, where the ‘id’ ‘balance’ and such are. Im not sure to how to return the ‘amount’ value after i get all of the data from the python command ‘get_primary_account()’

Comment: I should say client.get_primary_account(). My bad, should have proofread better

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the solution. Doubt anyone else will have the same issue I did as mine was just not understanding API's very well, but to retrieve my balance for my primary account I simply had to type the following:

```
  primacct=client.get_primary_account()
  btcBal=str(primacct['balance'])
```

I was overcomplicating things for no reason.. Hopefully this also clears up what my question was in the first place to those who read it.